# "document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].style" or "document.body.style"

Tags: javascript, css, styles

Some people use:

`document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].style`

and others use:

`document.body.style`.

Is there a difference between the two?

EDIT: An example of the first option: http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/find-the-vendor-prefix-of-the-current-browser/

Comment: Do you mean `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style`? Style doesn't make sense for script tags...

Comment: totally different use case, one for css style other for the script tag

Comment: Second one `document.body.style` is faster than other.

Comment: Maybe the first option is to avoid errors if has not been loaded yet the 'body' tag... ?? The 'script' tag has been loaded insurance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style`.

They are essentially the same, although I believe `document.body.style` is the newer and generally preferred method.

In terms of speed, `document.body.style` is also [**quite a bit faster than the former**](http://jsperf.com/document-body-style) in all major browsers, so I'd advise using that if picking between the two.

Comment: I meant `code document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].style`
For example here: http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/find-the-vendor-prefix-of-the-current-browser/

Comment: @Misgiving They are using `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]` not `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].style`. The first one gets all elements with the script tag name, second would be used to affect the style of those elements but you wouldn't do that because they're script elements. `document.body.style` is for the style of the documents body, e.g. `document.body.style.background="red"` could be used for setting the documents background to the color red.

Comment: That helped me, but the intention is get all supported properties, not set. I think the first option is safer for it. ¿What do you think?

Comment: @Misgiving I guess there's no actual harm in it if you don't mind the speed issue. You'd use `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` to get all, `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]` to get the first.